# Does the community user "auto-reject" suggested edits?

Tags: support, editing

I suggested an edit to a question:

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/3120

The edit was rejected by Community ♦. I don't really mind it being rejected, it wasn't a superb edit, but I think it did improve the quality of the question. My question about this is that the edit I made was later done by another user, and his edit wasn't rejected (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/11720/revisions). I was wondering why his edit wasn't rejected and mine was (even though mine was actually a bit better).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The post's author was in the process of editing his post when you submitted your edit. He then submitted his edit, which - since he has full editing rights to the post - was given precedence over your (as-yet unapproved) suggested edit. This caused your edit to be rejected by the system itself - no actual human ever reviewed it.

You might be interested in this feature-request: [Dismiss suggested edits which conflict with full edit instead of auto rejecting them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171469/dismiss-suggested-edits-which-conflict-with-full-edit-instead-of-auto-rejecting)

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Techtrekker has enough reputation that his/her edits do not need approval. I can't speak as to why yours was rejected, though.